# Remove observation before certain row

Tags: r

I have a data frame and I want to compute the mean across the variable `value` for all the period excluding +- two observations before/after that the crisis is `1` (i don't care about missing val). The calculation should be done by country (even though here in the example below I have only one country). Example:

```
country <- rep("AT",10)
value <- seq(1,10,1)
crisis <- c(0,0,0,NA,0,1,0,NA,0,0)

df <- data.frame(country, value, crisis)
df


mean(df$value[df$crisis == 0], na.rm=TRUE)

# expected result

exp_mean <- (1+2+3+9+10)/5
exp_mean

edit:
```

I would like to get a general case where we take into account other possible 1 in the dataset, for instance if we have

`crisis[10] = 1`
the result should be `(3+9)/2`

in order not to consider the periods after the first crisis but that actually experience a crisis at the second perdiod. Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Another base R solution, using `outer` + `c` + `unique` to filter out rows, i.e.,

```
r <- mean(na.omit(df[-unique(c(outer(which(df$crisis==1),-2:2,"+"))),"value"]))
```

such that

```
> r
[1] 5
```

Answer (score 2):

We can write a function which excludes the variables which are +- 2 observations after `crisis = 1`.

```
custom_mean <- function(c, v) {
   inds <- which(c == 1)
   mean(v[-unique(c(sapply(inds, `+`, -2:2)))], na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

`sapply` is used assuming there could be multiple `crisis = 1` situations for a country.

We can then apply this function for each `country`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(country) %>% summarise(exp_mean = custom_mean(crisis, value))

# A tibble: 1 x 2
#  country exp_mean
#  <fct>      <dbl>
#1 AT             5
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I generalized the case to consider more than 1 crisis inside the accounting period

Comment: @Jordan_b My code already handles more than 1 crisis condition. However, I don't understand why do you only consider 3 and 9 in your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply. We should not count when value == 10 because there there is a crisis. Furthermore, if I set the periods in the equation to be -20 +20 for instance the code doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I don't quite follow. Why is there a crisis when value == 10? I thought there is crisis only when `crisis == 1`.

Comment: Sorry I edited the question with two crisis, the second on the last observation

Comment: yes and that is why I am asking the logic of selecting only 3rd and 9th observation. I don't get it.

Comment: You are right sorry. Is there a way to account for longer periods than 2? I get an error

Comment: @Jordan_b I am not sure how you are applying it. As far as I see for the current example it runs without an error.

Comment: Using the formula in the definition ```sapply(inds, `+`, -2:2))``` the code is running. But when I use instead of -2/+2 numbers higher than 6 (e.g. +-8) that it stops and says: ```Error in v[-unique(c(sapply(inds, `+`, -8:8)))] : 
  only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts```

Comment: @Jordan_b look like `sapply(inds, \`+\`, -8:8)` generates negative values. Can you remove them? `inds <- unique(sapply(inds, \`+\`, -8:8))` and then do `mean(v[-inds[inds > 0]], na.rm = TRUE)`.

Answer (score 1):

This solution using base R works as long as there is only one value with 'crisis == 1' and as long as there are always two rows befor and after the row with 'crisis == 1'

```
country <- rep("AT",10)
value <- seq(1,10,1)
crisis <- c(0,0,0,NA,0,1,0,NA,0,0)

df <- data.frame(country, value, crisis)
df

df[(which(df$crisis == 1) - 2):(which(df$crisis == 1) + 2), ]
```

This solution does **not** work for this data:

```
country <- rep("AT",11)
value <- seq(1,11,1)
crisis <- c(0,0,0,NA,0,1,0,NA,0,0,1)

df2 <- data.frame(country, value, crisis)


df2[(which(df2$crisis == 1) - 2):(which(df2$crisis == 1) + 2), ]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the nice solution. Indeed I am looking for a general case with more than 1 crisis inside the 2 periods before/after the first crisis